# I am unable to figure out why I am getting an infinite loop in Python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, infinite-loop

I'm unable to figure out why I am getting an infinite loop ??

Here's the code:

```
# LAB  -   FIND SUM OF NUMBERS   1-10,  20-37,  35-89
sum = 0
i = 0
sum += i
for i in range(1,11):
    print('sum from 1-10 is ' ,sum)
```

Comment: You're not getting infinite loop but your code simply doesn't do what it should.

Comment: you sum addition is outside of the loop but must be inside

Comment: How are you deciding on what range to sum?  Your homework assignment has 3 ranges.

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want:

```
mysum = 0 
for i in range(1,11):
    mysum += i

print('sum from 1-10 is ' ,mysum)
```

Also possible:

```
mysum = sum(range(11))
print('sum from 1-10 is ' , mysum)
```

Comment: You shouldn't overwrite the [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum) built-in.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the loop wrong.

Here's a pythonic way of summing number between 1 and 10:

```
sum(range(11))
sum(range(20,38))
sum(range(35,90))
```

edited: according to @bereal and @l4mpi comments

Here's a less pythonic way of achieving the same:

```
mysum = 0
for i in range(1,11):
    mysum += i
print mysum
```

Comment: why not just `sum(range(1, 11))`?

Comment: Or even `sum(range(11))` - the `0` doesn't matter for the sum.

Comment: @l4mpi right ! Just giving him a hint for the `20-37` and `35-89`.